# how to test using monkeyrunner with android studio?

Tags: android-studio, jython, monkeyrunner

I have downloaded the android studio and the android sdk . I am handicapped beyond this point. It would be great if anyone could help me out beyond this point.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

or http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html

Comment: @Rithe According to the manual (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html#SampleProgram), monkeyrunner has nothing in common with Monkey tester.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best you can do is to use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).
Because **AndroidViewClient/culebra** is based on python instead of jython you won't have some of the problems you may encounter using monkeyrunner.